# Most Effecient way to parse Evtx files for specific content

Tags: python, windows, powershell, pandas

I have hundreds of gigs of Evtx security event logs I want to parse for specific Event IDs (4624) and usernames (joe) based on the Event IDs. I have attempted to use Powershell cmdlet like below:

```
get-winevent -filterhashtable @{Path="mypath.evtx"; providername="securitystuffprovider"; id=4624}
```

I know I can pass a variable containing a list to the Path parameter for all of my evtx files, but I am unable to filter based on a subset of the message of the EVTX. Also, this takes an incredibly long time to parse just one Evtx file much less 150 or so. I know there is a python package to parse Evtx but I am not sure how that would look as the python-evtx parser doesn't provide great examples of importing and using the package itself. I can not extract all of the data into csv as that would take too much disk space. Any ideas on how would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: [An approach to analyze windows event logs](http://undernexus.com/2014/07/10/windows-eventlogs/)??

Comment: Yes, the below command allows me to filter but doesn't provide all of my data points of the full event log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-Path` with the `-FilterXPath` parameter, and then filter using an XPath expression like so:

```
$Username = 'jdoe'
$XPathFilter = "*[System[(EventID=4624)] and EventData[Data[@Name='SubjectUserName'] and (Data='$Username')]]"

Get-WinEvent -Path C:\path\to\log\files\*.evtx -FilterXPath $XPathFilter
```